# How big are the prime factors of $2^kp - 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

*I have already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432259/how-big-are-the-factors-of-2kp-1). No answers despite the bounty (which has now ended)*

Let $p$ be a prime number, $p > 3$.

> Does there always exist $k \in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$ such that the prime factors of $2^kp - 1$ are all less than $p$?

### Thoughts

Well, we can easily see that if $2p - 1$ is *not* prime, then there are no primes bigger than $p$ which divide it (hence $k=1$ would work). But $2p-1$ being prime is pretty common when $p$ is prime; it happens with $p= 7,19, 37$ etc.

For those last values I looked at $k=2$, and they all work, but there is a prime less than $100$ (I don't remember which one) for which you have to use $k=3$.

Anyhow, it seems like a good bet, but is it actually true?

*Note*: It seems like an interesting question, but if it's not up to the standards of mathoverflow tell me and I'll remove it :-)

Comment: Nice question.  Consider the expression modulo a small prime q, to find what k works for a given residue class mod q.  My guess is there will be a k not much larger than log p (or smaller) which works (because 2^k will be smaller than the product of small primes q which it "hits").  Gerhard "Might Even Be True Unconditionally" Paseman, 2016.02.07.

Comment: How far up have you tested this, Ant?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Personally, I haven't. But there is a comment under the linked question (the one I posted on math.stackexchange) by Peter that said that "for $p < 4 \cdot 10^8$, there is a $k \le 9$ doing the job"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we consider a more general problem: given an integer $n \gt 1$, is there an integer $k \gt 0$ so that $2^kn - 1$ is $n$-friable (has all its prime factors of size at most $n$)?  I initially suspected the answer was no for small integers and yes for large integers.  It turns out (that I have convinced myself that) the answer is yes for $5,7,8,9,11,13$ and no for $2,3,4,6,10,12$.  I am looking at $14$, and suggest that this generalization is of interest.  (I'll let someone else suggest replacing 2 or 1 or both by integer parameters.)

Gerhard "Is Amazed At Question Growth" Paseman, 2016.02.07.

Comment: nice! Can you sketch an outline on how you convinced yourself that it works for $5,7,8,9,11,13$ and that it does not for $2,3,4,6,10,12$? :-)

Comment: Sort of, but I don't call it a proof yet because I haven't written it down.  In general, things look like 2^kr= 1 + stu, where r is a prime dividing n and s,t, and u are (possibly trivial) prime powers. s t and u aren't powers of 2 or r, and congruence conditions usually make t and u equal to 1.  Now Zsigmondy limits how big s can be, and trial shows no solutions with k large and nonzero.  For yes answers, a small amount of computation is enough..  Gerhard "It All Falls Into Place" Paseman, 2016.02.08.

Comment: I'm slow today.  2*14 - 1= 27.  It seems best to compute for a few small k and then go for a proof of impossibility.  Gerhard "And Not Other Way Around" Paseman, 2016.02.08.